# PHP DateTime diff countdown

Tags: php, datetime

I've got the following code that compares the difference between the now time and a given future time which is usually ahead of now time. However, when the future time is ahead it works but then when the now time passes the future time the timer goes upwards instead of counting down:

```
$now = new DateTime();
$future_date = new DateTime('2019-03-12T22:03:01Z');
$interval = $future_date->diff($now);

echo $interval->format("%im %ss");
```

Is there a way I can only return the time remaining only if it's upcoming?

Comment: The `DateTimeInterval` class has a flag, telling you if the difference is positive or negative

Comment: See `$interval->invert` ~ http://php.net/manual/class.dateinterval.php#dateinterval.props.invert

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($interval->invert>=1){
    echo $interval->format("%im %ss");
}
```